# Dynamically fetching property of Node Neo4j

Tags: spring-data-neo4j

This is my Neo4jRepository method

```
@Query("match (pofr:NODE) where pofr.param1= {param1} return pofr.{param2}, pofr.param3")
    List<Node> getPropertiesOfNode(@Param("param1") String param1, @Param("param2") String param2);
```

ExceptionLogs:

```
    Error executing Cypher; Code: Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError; Description: Invalid input '{': expected an identifier, whitespace, a function name or a property key name (line 1, column 64 (offset: 63))
"match (pofr:NODE) where pofr.param1 = {param1} return pofr.{param2}, pofr.param3"
                                                                ^; nested exception is org.neo4j.ogm.exception.CypherException: Error executing Cypher; Code: Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError; Description: Invalid input '{': expected an identifier, whitespace, a function name or a property key name (line 1, column 64 (offset: 63))
```

I'm facing issue while attempted to populate property data dynamically. Do we have any other approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Since Cypher does not support placeholders at those positions it is unfortunately not possible to solve this in Spring Data Neo4j.